# TopLevel OOP Questions

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am new to coding and tkinter. I'm working on making a YT Downloader using youtube_dl and tkinter, and I have several questions about TopLevel and OOP in general.

Here is a simplified version of my code (I just removed the other button, pictures, etc)

```
from tkinter import Button,Frame,Label,Toplevel,Tk

class Welcome:
   def __init__(self,parent):
      self.parent = parent
      self.parent.title("YT Downloader")
      self.parent.geometry("600x600")
      self.video_button = Button(self.parent, text = "Download a video", command = self.OpenVidDown)
      self.video_button.place(relx = .3, rely=.6, relwidth = .4, relheight = .1)

   def OpenVidDown(self):
      DownVid(self.parent)

class DownVid(Toplevel):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      parent.withdraw()
      Toplevel.__init__(self)
      self.geometry("551x600")
      self.title("Video Downloader")

def main():
   main = Tk()
   opening_screen = Welcome(main)
   main.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

1. Did I properly implement TopLevel in the DownVid class?
2. If I used `super().__init__()` instead to initalize the TopLevel, why do I have to pass parent as a parameter instead of self? How do you know when to use self or parent?
3. Why did using `self.geometry()` work in the DownVid class when I had to use `self.parent.geometry()` in the Welcome class?

Any help would be greatly apprciated!

Comment: Not the question to ask on SO (also can't ask multiple questions), maybe better suits CodeReview. 1, what do you mean by properly? does it work? if yes then probably all is fine. 2. take a look at some OOP tutorials, one simply doesn't need `self` as first argument while the other does. 3. Welcome class is not a container, it just affects the container which is `parent` so you need to change the `parent` stuff, `DownVid` is a window itself (because of inheritance) so it has that attribute inherited

Comment: I would suggest looking at some object oriented programming tutorials that focus on python. Also `super().function(*args, **kwargs)` is the same as `BaseClass.function(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: For 2), if you used `super().__init__()` instead of `Toplevel.__init__(self)` you would not need to pass `self`. Either way, passing a `parent` argument to `Toplevel` is optional — whether you need it depends on what you're doing (usually you don't need to pass it but for this you might). For 3), because `Welcome` isn't a subclass of anything.

Comment: @Matiiss: I don't think this question's quite ready to be posted on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I properly implement TopLevel in the DownVid class?

Not quite. You need to be passing the parent to `Toplevel.__init__`.

```
Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
```

In this case, omitting `parent` is harmless since the default will be the root window. However, it's a best practice to always pass a parent for every widget except the root window. Widgets exist in a hierarchy, and it's good to be explicit in defining that hierarchy.

Also, I would argue that it shouldn't call `withdraw` on its parent. To me, that should be the responsibility of the code that creates the new window.

> If I used `super().__init__()` instead to initalize the TopLevel, why do I have to pass parent as a parameter instead of self?

Every widget except the root window needs a parent. You should always supply the parent whether you call `Toplevel.__init__` or if you call `super().__init__`.

> Why did using `self.geometry()` work in the DownVid class when I had to use `self.parent.geometry()` in the Welcome class?

Because the `Welcome` class is not a top-level window. It's not a widget at all, so calling a method like `geometry` on something that isn't a widget is going to fail.